# Resize HD Image using Fabric js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am new to fabric js. So, currently I am trying to resize a HD image using fabric js. but image is not resizing after some particular size

**Fabric Canvas**
canvas = new fabric.Canvas("tcanvas", {
imageSmoothingEnabled: false,
enableRetinaScaling: false,
fireRightClick: true,
stopContextMenu: true,
});

Code when I click on any image to put that image on Canvas

```
 $(".img-polaroid").click(function (e) {
var el = e.target;
/*temp code*/
var offset = 50;
var left = fabric.util.getRandomInt(0 + offset, 200 - offset);
var top = fabric.util.getRandomInt(0 + offset, 400 - offset);
var angle = fabric.util.getRandomInt(-20, 40);
var width = fabric.util.getRandomInt(30, 50);
var opacity = (function (min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
})(0.5, 1);

fabric.Image.fromURL(el.src, function (image) {
  image.set({
    left: left,
    top: top,
    angle: 0,
    padding: 10,
    cornersize: 10,
    hasRotatingPoint: true,
  });
  //image.scale(getRandomNum(0.1, 0.25)).setCoords();
  canvas.add(image);
});
```

});

Comment: Can you post a working snippet or fiddle demonstrating this issue?

Comment: @melchiar the code is pretty big. also I am not that familier with fiddle. If you want I can share the compressed folder of that

Comment: jsfiddle or codepen allow more code

Answer (score 1):

To resize an image with FabricJS, use the `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties. If you want to set your image to specific dimensions, use the methods `scaleToWidth()` and `scaleToHeight()`

```
//scales the image to a width of 100
img.scaleToWidth(100);

//scales the image to a height of 100
img.scaleToHeight(100);
```